Solana logsSubscribe (Websocket Method)
My goals is to monitor each token's transactions (buys/sells) on Raydium, live.
For that I use "logsSubscribe" WS method that returns ray_logs
Example JSON 'ray_log' decoded:
    {
  "name": "swapBaseIn",
  "data": {
    "logType": 3,
    "amountIn": "21514983692",
    "minimumOut": "0",
    "direction": "1",
    "userSource": "21514983692",
    "poolCoin": "140696852628033375",
    "poolPc": "21316786476678",
    "outAmount": "141507531909869"
  }
}

First way:
Subscribe to Raydium's LiquidityPoolV4 program (main AMM that will be streaming every transaction that is happening on Raydium) and then filter & sort these transactions. Problem with this way is logs don't contain Mint address of a token being involved.
Example of single output from 'logsSubscribe' method:

Second way:
Subscribe to each individual liquidity pool (pair) and monitor its logs. But say there are 2000+ pairs. Is it too many concurrent WS subscriptions opened OR might actually just be a scale problem?
Any help appreciated, thank yall!

I don't have a direct script to help you out (I'll probably do one later though), but having dealt with a similar issue I found what works for this, and I think is probably the most efficient solution—using blockSubscribe to monitor the program address and decode those transactions live as they come.
The blockSubscribe method contains full transactions, while logsSubscribe is always very limited for such cases.
Here's an example that you can check for the implementation logic, which is basically:

stream all program-related transaction via blockSubcribe with the transactions details set to full.
decode them usually using an IDL — Raydium for example has several.

Here's an example: Listening to pump.fun migrations to Raydium
Check out the "Monitoring Raydium migrations" section specifically.
Hope this helps!
